# Exchange Server 2007 Transport Errors -- SMTP Session Hangs

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2007

I was doing some changes to the server (writing an Transport Agent). After trying to install it, I started to get some errors.

Now, when connecting to the SMTP server the session hangs just after finishing the DATA section. I'm not sure what happened, I disabled my transport agent and uninstalled it, then restarted the server. The problem persists.

In the Event Viewer, four of the same errors show up:

Source: FSCTransportScanner
Category: Scan Error
Event ID: 5021
Description: Unable to retrieve internet monitor interface.

What could have happened?

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have Forefront installed on that server? There is a [KB article here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934286) that describes this problem, and a solution, it may be worth trying the solution even if you don't have Forefront.